# Creating a Simple Shopping Cart with PHP, JavaScript and Html?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am attempting to create a shopping cart using PHP for a Shirt Design Website. Users can design the shirts and then add them to the cart. So I created a form, in which users can pick their colour and sizes:

```
<form action="cart_main.php">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Colour:</td><td> <select>
        <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
        <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
        <option value="Black">Black</option>
        <option value="Grey">Grey</option>
        <option value="Beige">Beige</option>
        <option value="White">White</option>
        </select></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Design:</td><td> <select>
        <option value="T1">Skull</option>
        <option value="T2">Liquify</option>
        <option value="T3">Wings</option>
        <option value="T4">Small Skull</option>
        <option value="T5">Cogs</option>
        <option value="T6">Safety Pin</option>
        </select></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Pop Colour: </td><td> <select>
        <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>            
        <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
        <option value="Purple">Purple</option>
        </select></td></tr>
        <tr><td><button id="addToCart" name="addToCart">Add to Cart</button></td></tr>

</table>
</form>
```

I need to simply create a shopping cart that will display all of the added items and total price when viewed by the user. This wouldn't be too hard, if it was a single value, but since I need to send/store 3 values; Colour, Design and Pop Colour, I am not sure how i should do it.

I have tried:

```
> Sending the selected data to a table in a database. And then getting the whole table when viewing the Cart
> Using javascript to Find the ID of a shirt depending of what has been selected (Failed)
```

So my QUESTION is:

How would i create a shopping cart for something like this in the simplest manner. Or how do i send multiple values accross and group them so i can create a cart.

Thank you Very Much!!

Comment: Do you actually get an error?  What's wrong with what you have? Just from looking, you need to name your inputs at the very least.

Comment: Well im not getting an error. My issue is much rather I dont know how to send all that information into a cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Steps to create shopping cart:**

1) Have an object to store the values eg. product

```
product = { 
// product properties

color: "color", 
design: "skull", 
popColor: "color"
}
```

2) On submit of the form, in `cart_main.php` fetch the values and populate in the product object

3) You need to have a cart array.

4) To that cart array, add the object. So now you have list of objects inside the cart array.

In the UI you just need to show the count of objects in the array.

When they cart is clicked, you need to iterate the objects and populate the properties

Comment: Ok. I tried what you suggested. I am running into a problem. So does the form call a javascript function that adds a new object? And if so, how is this object accessible from the cart page?

Comment: Yes you need to have javascript function to handle submit of the form. On submission of the form, construct the request json using key value pair and send it to PHP. It will populate in products object and will add to cart array and will return the cart array. On success of that method, update the cart based on the cart array you receive from the server. Hope you are clear :)